# Can "who will visit" in "The number of people who will visit Japan this year will reach 19 million. " be simplified into "who visit"

Tags: relative-clauses

> (1) It is estimated that the number of people **who will visit** Japan this year will reach 19 million.

> (2) It is estimated that the number of people **who visit** Japan this year will reach 19 million.

Am I right in thinking **who visit** in (2) is simplified version of **who will visit** in (1). There is a similar sentence in 556 "Tense Simplification" of *Practical English Usage* by Michael Swan:

> He says he'll give five pounds to anybody **who finds** his pen.

Comment: In that context, yes, **will** is not required, even if it said "next year".  But I wouldn't call "who visit" a "simplified version".  And **who visit** could be replaced with **visiting** or **who will have visited**.

Comment: Interestingly, 'who will visit' and 'who visit' are both available here, whereas 'He says he'll give five pounds to anybody who will find his pen' sounds wrong in the pure future sense and somewhat strange in the 'will undertake to' sense. A padded 'He says he'll give five pounds to anybody who will find his pen for him' becomes more idiomatic.

Comment: It sounds strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

If you say "the number of people who visit Japan every year", that makes sense, because you are relating existing information.

On the other hand, when referring to this year, which isn't yet finished, that number doesn't exist. The fact that a prediction is made about the number underlines that it doesn't exist yet. I think that "who **will** visit" should not be reduced to "who visit" in that example.

Your other example doesn't fit, because the main clause contains the contracted "he will", which puts the whole thing in a hypothetical future.

Comment: The sentence 2's main clause too contains "will reach". Doesn't this justifies the reduction of "will visit" to "visit"?

Comment: I don't think so. When you say "the number of people who visit Japan each year", you are making a general statement. But when you are talking about a particular year, it's not a general statement, so I think the verb should be inflected for tense.